# How to add a if condition in Xml Element

Tags: c#

We are creating an xml document which has following elements name,Dob,document year,etc.
The Document year will varies for each year.
Based on this year i need to change xml element.

For exmaple for 2017 i have xmlelement properties as Name,dob,document year.
and for 2018 i need to have firstname,middlename,Last name,dob,document year.

i create the xml element as follows

```
        [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != name)
                {
                    name= value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }
```

If we open a xml document for the year of 2017 
i need display in xml as name,dob,document year

If i need to open xml document for the year of 2018
i need to display in xml as firstname,middlename,lastname.

how to conditionally change the xml element based on year.

thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like this not a task for the xml element, you can have different serialized classes for every year.

Comment: Deserialize the both XML documents for the same year then put a condition to detect the year, dispose the unneeded XML file.